# Schedule running a reactive stream for every 1 min

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactive-kafka

I have a reactive stream that gets some data, loops through the data, processes the data, finally writes the data to Kafka

```
public Flux<M> sendData(){

     Flux.fromIterable(o.getC()).publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(id->
                        Flux.fromIterable(getM(id)).publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                                .flatMap( n -> {
                                    return Flux.fromIterable(o.getD()).publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                                            .flatMap(d -> return Flux.just(sendToKafka));
                                })
                )
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    log.debug("Error while reading data : {} ", throwable.getMessage());
                    return;
                })
                .subscribe();
}


public void run(String... args){
        sendData();
    }
```

I want this workflow to be run every minute. Can some one help me understand how to schedule this within the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want to run something per minute.

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .flatMap(n -> sendData())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.
I added .startWith(interval) so the first process starts immediately and the subsequent processes runs based on the interval